# Chrom Extension: onDeterminingFilenme interfers with all downloads

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I'm coding an extension that downloads items with specific names. Currently, I have two types of items to download:

- Items that have the link to the file URL, so it can be directly downloaded and its name determined by `chrome.downloads.download` (type A)
- Items that don't have the link to the file URL, and had to be downloaded via a direct download link. The download process has to be initiated separately and its file name changed with `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener` (type B)

The problem is `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener` interfere with all downloads regardless of the parameters set. I want it only to change the filename when the type B item is downloaded.

Basic rundown of my code

```
chrome.downloads.download({ //type A items
      url: item.imageLink, //set linkURL
      filename: setName //set name
    });
//item will be downloaded with *setName*
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener((downloadItem, suggest) => { //type B items
//item will be intercepted, its name being its original filename
  if (item != null && item.type == "B" && downloadItem.url == item.imageLink) { //check linkURL
    suggest({filename: setName, conflictAction: "uniquify"}); //item's filename will be changed to *setName*
  }  
});
```

Unless I remove the `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename` completely, the file downloaded will be its original filename regardless of what type it is.

I thought of 3 possible solutions:

1. Brute force the `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename`, make it change the name of every item downloaded.

- Problem: it'll mess up other downloads, including those from other extensions

2. Remove `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename` when it's not type B items, and add it in when it is.

- Problem: no guarantee when it will be removed to not interfere with other items being downloaded simultaneously when it's running

3. Figure out how to download type B items without using `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename`

- Problem: I've tried it, I've found nothing on converting direct download links to fileURLs, especially if the direct download link is generated uniquely

Any other suggestions or am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome, but unfortunately the person responsible for this API misunderstood the problem in https://crbug.com/1106297, and now ignores our attempts to bring the issue up [again](https://crbug.com/1122898). Consider opening yet another issue and describe your use case; let's hope you get lucky and the issue is properly fixed.

Comment: Oh, then it's not just me then. 
hmmm

Still doesn't solve my problem. :/

Comment: If you know the type in advance: could you fetch the data, make a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), initiate download of the blob and provide the filename when you initiate this download?

Comment: I don't think I know the type in advance? 
I have the direct download link, can I make a blob of it?

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you think it would do anything to open another bugreport? I have a use case where I'd like to cancel the download and start a "manual" one with chrome.downloads.download to move it into another directory. If I cancel the download in chrome.downloads.onCreated the saveAs window will *sometimes* still open. But if i cancel it in onDeterminingFilename I run into the above described bug.